# Jodatime/Spring MVC/Jackson | DateTime formatting issue

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jodatime

When I use the @ResponseData JodaTime is converted into it's full object state, even though I have a custom serializer in place.

**Configuration:**

Spring 3.1.2
Jackson 1.9.11

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Custom Serializer:

```
public class JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    //TODO Bad (hard) code. This should be part of a global system setting through ConfigurationService
    private static final String dateFormat = ("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).print(date);
        logger.debug("Converted date string: {}", formattedDate);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Dispatcher:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Usage:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer.class)
    public DateTime getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }
```

The output I'm getting is similar to this:

```
"dateCreated":{"monthOfYear":12,"yearOfEra":2012,"yearOfCentury":12,"centuryOfEra":20,"millisOfSecond":359,"millisOfDay":53080359,"secondOfMinute":40,"secondOfDay":53080,"minuteOfHour":44,"minuteOfDay":884,"hourOfDay":14,"weekyear":2012,"weekOfWeekyear":51,"year":2012,"dayOfMonth":19,"dayOfWeek":3,"era":1,"dayOfYear":354,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":false,"id":"Asia/Riyadh"}},"millis":1355917480359,"zone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":false,"id":"Asia/Riyadh"},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"dateModified":{"monthOfYear":12,"yearOfEra":2012,"yearOfCentury":12,"centuryOfEra":20,"millisOfSecond":359,"millisOfDay":53080359,"secondOfMinute":40,"secondOfDa
```

Where I want a simple dd/mm/yyyy date.

Please advice.

Additionally, how can I set this formatting rule globally where I don't have to use @JsonSerialize all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/spring/webmvc/mvc_spring_config_namespace.html) helped with the situation.

Basically you need a Serializer and custom object mapper for jackson.

The serializer:

```
public class JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    private static final String dateFormat = ("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime date, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat).print(date);
        json.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Custom Object Mapper:

```
public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomJacksonObjectMapper(){
        CustomSerializerFactory factory = new CustomSerializerFactory();
        factory.addSpecificMapping(DateTime.class, new JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer());
        this.setSerializerFactory(factory);
    }

}
```

Now register the Custom mapper with MVC

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="customJacksonMapper" />
                </bean>
            </mvc:message-converters>
        </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And that works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) module which can be used for this - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14185077/125246

Comment: I would assume due to the above being jackson 2.0+ and original question states jackson 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

As paulcm mentioned there is jackson jodatype module which will allow serialization without @JsonSerializer. You can check working configuration here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399927/1134683