# Spring + Jackson + joda time: how to specify the serialization/deserialization format?

Tags: spring-mvc, format, jackson, jodatime, spring-boot

I have the following class:

```
public static class ARestRequestParam
{
    String name;
    LocalDate date;  // joda type
}
```

And I want it to be deserialized from the following JSON which is processed by jackson.

{ name:"abc", date:"20131217" }

Actually, I want to deserialize any LocalDate field in any class with "yyyyMMdd" format, without duplicating the format string, without adding any setter method, without any XML configuration. (That is, annotation and Java code is preferable)
How can it be done?

Also, I also want to know the serialization part. that is, LocalDate -> "yyyyMMdd".

I've seen followings:

- jackson-datatype-joda (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda)
- custom serializer (public class JodaDateTimeJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer { ... } - [Spring @ResponseBody Jackson JsonSerializer with JodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649356/spring-responsebody-jackson-jsonserializer-with-jodatime))
- @JsonCreator
- @DateTimeFormat

But I don't know which is applicable, and which is most up-to-date.

BTW, I use Spring Boot.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I have managed to write working code for the deserialization part.
It is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
    {
        converters.add(jacksonConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter()
    {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new ApiJodaModule());
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

        return converter;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private class ApiJodaModule extends SimpleModule
    {
        public ApiJodaModule()
        {
            addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new ApiLocalDateDeserializer());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class ApiLocalDateDeserializer
        extends StdScalarDeserializer<LocalDate>
    {
        private static DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");

        public ApiLocalDateDeserializer() { super(LocalDate.class); }

        @Override
        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
        {
            if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)
            {
                String s = jp.getText().trim();
                if (s.length() == 0)
                    return null;
                return LocalDate.parse(s, formatter);
            }
            throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.NOT_AVAILABLE,
                "expected JSON Array, String or Number");
        }
    }
}
```

I had to implement the deserializer myself, since the datetime format for the deserializer in jackson-datatype-joda cannot be altered. So, since I've implemented the deserializer myself, jackson-datatype-joda is not needed. (although I've copied pieces of its code)

Is this code Ok?
Is this up-to-date solution?
Is there any other easier way?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Following Dave Syer's suggestion, I modified the source above as follows:

Removed 2 methods: configureMessageConverters(), jacksonConverter()
Added following method into WebMvcConfiguration class:

```
@Bean
public Module apiJodaModule()
{
    return new ApiJodaModule();
}
```

But now it does not work. It seems apiJodaModule() is ignored.
How can I make it work?
(It seems that I should not have a class that has @EnableWebMvc to use that feature.)

The version I use is org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6.

**UPDATE**

Final working version is as follows: (with other configurations I've done previously in the class that had @EnableWebMvc)
As Dave Syer mentioned, this will only work on BUILD-SNAPSHOT version, at least for now.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter apiWebMvcConfiguration()
    {
        return new ApiWebMvcConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserInterceptor userInterceptor()
    {
        return new UserInterceptor();
    }

    public class ApiWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
        {
            registry.addInterceptor(userInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/api/user/**");
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
        {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Module apiJodaModule()
    {
        return new ApiJodaModule();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class ApiJodaModule extends SimpleModule
    {
        public ApiJodaModule()
        {
            addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new ApiLocalDateDeserializer());
        }

        private static final class ApiLocalDateDeserializer
            extends StdScalarDeserializer<LocalDate>
        {
            public ApiLocalDateDeserializer() { super(LocalDate.class); }

            @Override
            public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp,
                DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
            {
                if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)
                {
                    String s = jp.getText().trim();
                    if (s.length() == 0)
                        return null;
                    return LocalDate.parse(s, localDateFormatter);
                }
                throw ctxt.mappingException(LocalDate.class);
            }
        }

        private static DateTimeFormatter localDateFormatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is OK, but if you use `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring Boot app you switch off the default settings in the framework, so maybe you should avoid that. Also, you now have only *one* `HttpMessageConverter` in your MVC handler adapter. If you use a snapshot of Spring Boot you ought to be able to simply define a `@Bean` of type `Module` and everything else would be automatic, so I would recommend doing it that way.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I had to add addResourceHandlers() to WebMvcConfiguration class to serve static files(since default settings were gone). But since I overrode addInterceptors() to add URL interceptors,  I had to create my own class that has EnableWebMvc.

Comment: You don't need `@EnableWebMvc` in order to add interceptors, just add a `@Bean` of type `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` (standard Spring MVC feature). Read the answer: "use a snapshot". That should sort you out.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized the there can be multiple WebMvcConfigurerAdapters, by reading the spring source code. BTW, I don't know what exactly mean by "use a snapshot". How can I specify it in a build.gradle file? (My knowledge of Java development environment is too small) Since HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java was modified only 2 days ago, maybe the feature is not included in M6. So, should I download the spring boot from github?

Comment: No it is not included in M6, that's why you need a snapshot. If you have the right repository configuration (follow the [website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)) then you just change the version label from "M6" to "BUILD-SNAPSHOT".

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that. Sorry for asking such a basic question. BTW, only today I realized that the 'M' in 'M6' means 'milestone'...

Comment: It works. I've updated the question to include the final working version.

Comment: Is there any way modify the 'vanilla' ObjectMapper? As doc mentioned "If Jackson is on the classpath you already get a default converter with a vanilla ObjectMapper." As I known, if we set objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false); will get what we want.

Comment: Create a `@Bean` of type `ObjectMapper`