# Spring: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter bean registered twice

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

This is a followup question of [Spring + Jackson + joda time: how to specify the serialization/deserialization format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648706/spring-jackson-joda-time-how-to-specify-the-serialization-deserialization-f).

When I was writing the final version of the code, for the first time I wrote it as follows: (only relevant portion is shown)

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter apiWebMvcConfiguration()
    {
        return new ApiWebMvcConfiguration();
    }

    public class ApiWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    {
        public ApiWebMvcConfiguration()
        {
            log.debug("### ApiWebMvcConfiguration");
        }

        @Bean
        public UserInterceptor userInterceptor()
        {
            return new UserInterceptor(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
        {
            log.debug("### addInterceptors");
            registry.addInterceptor(userInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/api/user/**");
        }
    }

    private static final Log log =
        LogFactory.getLog(WebMvcConfiguration.class);
}
```

There is no @EnableWebMvc, since the default @EnableWebMvc class of Spring Boot is used.
Notice that userInterceptor bean is in the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, which is also a bean.

When I've run the application, following error occured:
(class pathnames of my classes were replaced to '...' by myself)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:609)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at ...Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...WebMvcConfiguration$ApiWebMvcConfiguration.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 15 more
```

Then I changed ApiWebMvcConfiguration class to a static inner class.

Application was started 'normally', but ApiWebMvcConfiguration class was instantiated twice. That is, "### ApiWebMvcConfiguration" was printed twice. And accordingly, "### addInterceptors" was printed twice.

Then, when UserIntercepter's code ran, it failed because of null @Autowired JdbcTemplate. That is, @Autowired was not working for the object. (JdbcTemplate was successfully @Autowired in other objects)

So, I changed the code to the final version as shown in [Spring + Jackson + joda time: how to specify the serialization/deserialization format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648706/spring-jackson-joda-time-how-to-specify-the-serialization-deserialization-f), that is, UserIntercepter bean was pulled out of ApiWebMvcConfiguration, the problem was gone.

Is this correct behaviour?
Should @Bean not be nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring tries to instantiate the `ApiWebMvcConfiguration` itself. That does not work because non-static inner classes cannot be instantiated like normal classes. They need a reference to an instance of the outer class. Hence the error message "No default constructor found".

When you change the inner class to a static one, instantiation works, but as you noticed, it still happens twice.

The problem is the  `@Bean`annotation for `userInterceptor()`. You tell Spring that it can get a bean from this method. But in order to get one, Spring needs an instance of `ApiWebMvcConfiguration`. So it creates one itself. But then another one is created by the `apiWebMvcConfiguration()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A nested class inside a @Configuration class is always interpreted as a @Bean. So you have registered it twice by adding your own explicit @Bean definition.

Comment: Thank you. But if apiWebMvcConfiguration() method is removed, ApiWebMvcConfiguration object is not instantiated at all. (Maybe I don't quite understand your explanation.)

Comment: As far as I know it will be instantiated (as long as it is `@Configuration` and static).