# Spring 3 with ResponseBody ignoring @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, inheritance, jackson

I can't make spring return a serialization of my object with the additional property defining the class.

My classes are:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="ObjectType")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=LiteStudy.class, name="LiteStudy")
})
public class Entity {
...
}


@JsonTypeName("LiteStudy")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Study.class, name="Study")
})
public class LiteStudy extends Entity {
...
}


@JsonTypeName("Study")
public class Study extends LiteStudy{
...
}
```

In my unit test, an Study instance is serialised properly, having the extra property for the class:

```
{"ObjectType":"Study",
...
}
```

Using for this a simple:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(studyJSON,study.getClass());
```

However, in my Spring Rest webservice module the study is serialized without the "ObjectType" property.

The controller looks like this (simplified):

```
@ResponseBody
public RestResponse<Study> getStudyById(@PathVariable("studyIdentifier")    String studyIdentifier) throws DAOException {

    return getStudyRestResponse(studyIdentifier);
}
```

EDIT: Adding RestResponse (Simplified)

```
public class RestResponse<Content> {

private Content content;
private String message;
private Exception err;

public Content getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(Content content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Exception getErr() {
    return err;
}

public void setErr(Exception err) {
    this.err = err;
}
```

Any idea why spring seems to be ignoring the @JsonType annotations?

Comment: Have you tried searching stackoverflow?
Perhaps some of these can help you: [Spring \@ResponseBody Jackson JsonSerializer with JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649356/spring-responsebody-jackson-jsonserializer-with-jodatime), [Spring configure \@ResponseBody JSON format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823358/spring-configure-responsebody-json-format)...

Comment: Thanks maricn...I don't have a custom ObjectMapper..and I wouldn't like to have one, if possible!. ;-) And yes I have searched stackoverflow and haven't found any answer to this question. Am I missing anything?

Comment: what is this class RestResponse?

Comment: RestResponse is a Wrapper class, i'll paste it. It will have a getContent() that returns the Study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return only the object you need, do not wrap it in generic wrapper class. Your problem is related to Java Type erasure. See more info [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336)

```
@ResponseBody
    public @ResponseBody Study getStudyById(@PathVariable("studyIdentifier")    String studyIdentifier) throws DAOException {

        return studyIdentifier;
    }
```

Comment: That was it!. Since I want to keep the RestResponse wrapper I created a class extending RestResponse like this: `public class StudyRestResponse extends RestResponse<Study> {
}`. This way I can keep the wrapper and, I guess, type erasure does not happen anymore. Many thanks.