# java Date Seralization : want to store the long value rather than the string representation

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I hava a map of type `Map<String, Object>`. I am converting it into a `JSONObject` and then serializing to JSON inside a jackson custom serializer(for some reason). One of the values in the map is of type `Date` and when serializing to JSON that date field is being serialized as a string like: "Mon Jun ....". But I want the millisecond value of type `long` instead. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Cant you call date.getTime () in your custom serializer?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3269459/642706) and answers about using a Jackson serializer for [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `Serializable` class to override the `Date` class's default  `toString()` method to convert the long millisecond value to string and return that as `toString()` output.