# serialization format datetime jackson joda spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson, jodatime

Howto serialize POJO. I'm using jackson, spring mvc 4, hibernate 4, joda time I have:

```
@Entity
public class MyPojo {

  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime") 
  private DateTime duedate;

//getters setters..
}


//my config:
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.EAGER_SERIALIZER_FETCH, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,false);
        return objectMapper;
    }


//my calling for deserialization POJO:

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String jsonDemand=ow.writeValueAsString(demand);
System.out.println("jsonDemand"+jsonDemand);
```

//from the output I'm always getting I think "deep" serialization like that:

```
 "duedate" : {
    "year" : 2014,
     "dayOfMonth" : 22,
     "dayOfWeek" : 4,
     "era" : 1,
     "dayOfYear" : 142,
     "weekOfWeekyear" : 21,
     "weekyear" : 2014,
     ...
  }
```

but I want simple serialization format like that "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize Joda DateTime with Jackson JSON processer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269459/how-to-serialize-joda-datetime-with-jackson-json-processer)

Comment: yes, custom serialization solve the problem, thanks James.