# Does Spring have a default OffsetDateTime Serializer?

Tags: jackson, spring-data-rest

I am using spring boot to create a spring data rest application.  I want to use ISO 8601 for serializing/deserializing OffsetDateTimes.  I have the following in my @Configuration.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.indentOutput(false).dateFormat(ISO8601DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance());
    return builder;
}
```

This works for older Date objects, but does not work with OffsetDateTime in Java 8.  Is there a standard solution to this, or do I need to write my own JsonSerializers (likely extended from StdScalarSerializer) and add the following:

```
builder
  .deserializerByType(OffsetDateTime.class, myCustomOffsetDateTimeDeserializer)
  .serializerByType(OffsetDateTime.class, myCustomOffsetDateTimeSerializer)
```

I feel like there must be some standard serializers/deserializers out there for these objects that I'm missing.  Are there?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper provides the solution to this question.

Comment: @ErikGillespie Thanks.  I must have searched for all the wrong things.  I put the dependency in my project and it's working fine now.