# @DateTimeFormat convert to JSON wrong format

Tags: java, spring, java-8

In my class I have date field:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
LocalDateTime date;
```

I use [DataTimeFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) because I want date format like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE_TIME) (for my REST controller):

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, e.g. "2000-10-31 01:30:00.000-05:00".

But it convert in JSON to (JSON array):

```
"date":[2016,1,6,6,53,29,859000000]
```

instead of like this (JSON string):

```
"date":"2016-01-06 06:53:29..."
```

---

I use dependency `jackson-datatype-jsr310` (because `jackson-databind` convert to object, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an excellent article on how to serialize JSON dates.

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

Option 12: Custom Serializer should be a last resort, but there are many solutions to choose from on that page.

Comment: This work: `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` instead of `@DateTimeFormat`. I get `date: "2016-01-06 06:53:29"`. Thanks.