# How to use object with single-charsequence constructors/factory methods instead of single-string ones inside request body for Rest?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a controller with method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response<Boolean> requestAppt(
        @RequestBody @Valid ApptRequest request
) {
    System.out.println(request);
    return Response.success(true);
}
```

My ApptRequest is:

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class ApptRequest implements Serializable{

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private OffsetDateTime date;

    public ApptRequest() {
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(OffsetDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to send a request with request body:

```
{
    "date": "2016-05-11T13:30:38+02:00"
}
```

I have an exception:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple
>   type, class java.time.OffsetDateTime] from String value
>   ('2016-05-11T13:30:38+02:00'); no single-String constructor/factory
>   method

It says that **OffsetDateTime should have a constructor or factory method with only one String parameter**.
But I found that it has needed **factory method with CharSequence parameter**:

```
/**
 * Obtains an instance of {@code OffsetDateTime} from a text string
 * such as {@code 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00}.
 * <p>
 * The string must represent a valid date-time and is parsed using
 * {@link java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME}.
 *
 * @param text  the text to parse such as "2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00", not null
 * @return the parsed offset date-time, not null
 * @throws DateTimeParseException if the text cannot be parsed
 */
public static OffsetDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

And if I try **to use date as request param instead of request body property** everything is working correctly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response<Boolean> requestAppt(
        @RequestParam @Valid @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime date
) {
    System.out.println(date);
    return Response.success(true);
}
```

May be I should specify the appropriate constructor manually using some annotations or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310 to classpath should help. Inspired by [JSON Java 8 LocalDateTime format in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot)