# Display LocalDateTime in Angular 2 using Spring REST (primeng)

Tags: spring, rest, angular, java-8, localdate

I'm using Java 8 date time in project Spring, 
but when I have display that date, I have : [object Object]

Server :

```
class Person {
   LocalDateTime dateCreation;
   ...
}
```

and

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @RequestMapping(value ="/getPerson", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<A> getPerson() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    ....
```

Client :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.PersonService.getPersons().subscribe(persons => this.persons = persons);
    }
```

and

```
export class Person {
    ....
    dateCreation:Date;
}
```

and person.html :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="persons" ...>
  <p-column field="dateCreation" header="DateCreation" [sortable]="true">
        <template let-col let-person="rowData" pTemplate="body">
              {{person.dateCreation|date}}
        </template>
  </p-column>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot : add the jsr310 dependency in your project .

Comment: Thanks pdem, this link solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks pdem, this link solve my problem
I'm using :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
private LocalDateTime dateCreation = ...
```

Comment: `LocalDateDeserialize` looks wrong shouldn't it have been `LocalDateTimeDeserialize`