# Instantiating POJO (LocalDateTime) from YAML Properties File (Java & Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, properties, yaml, pojo

I am trying to load custom properties from a YAML properties file upon initialization using Spring Boot. I have found countless tutorials on how to do that, and they work. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way how to instantiate POJOS, such as for example LocalDateTime. My code is as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="default-film-showings")
public class FilmShowings {
    private List<FilmShowing> filmShowings;

    //Constructors, Getters, setters etc.

    public static class FilmShowing {
        private Integer id;
        private Film film;
        private Theatre theatre;
        private LocalDateTime dateTime;

        //Constructors, Getters, setters etc.
    }
}
```

My YAML file is currently as follows

```
default-film-showings:
  filmShowings:
    - id: 1
      dateTime: 2018-07-13 21:00:00
```

My problem is that I get the following error upon initialisation

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'filmShowings[0].dateTime';
```

I also tried this variant

```
default-film-showings:
  filmShowings:
    - id: 1
      dateTime:
        date: 
          year: 2018
          month: 7
          day: 13
        time:
          hour: 21
          minute: 0
          second: 0
          nano: 0
```

but I got the following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'filmShowings': Could not bind properties to FilmShowings
```

Any help? I looked at the following thread [JSON Java 8 LocalDateTime format in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot/37219175) but it didn't solve my problem.

On a similar note, is there any way to link the Film POJO attribute to another default property?

Say I have the following in my properties file

```
default-films:
  films:
    - id: 1
      filmName: Spider-Man
```

can I add something like this too?

```
default-film-showings:
  filmShowings:
    - id: 1
      film: default-films.films[0]
      dateTime: whatever I need to do here to make it work
```

It is reading default-films.films[0] as string and thus not matching 'the YAML' object.

Any help?

Comment: What happens if you try with the string in ISO format. Example `2007-03-01T13:00:00` ?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I currently have someting like this `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ss HH:mm:dd", iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) private LocalDateTime dateTime;` and in the YAML i put `dateTime: "2007-03-01T13:00:00"`. Got the following error `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'`

Answer (score 4):

1. Assuming Spring honors the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation in a `@ConfigurationProperties` class (I haven't verified that), you've declared the format to be [DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME) which is `2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`. Your property file has `2018-07-13 21:00:00` which isn't any of the standard formats. How do you expect it to work?
2. Your datatype is `LocalDateTime` which doesn't have a concept of time zone, thus contradicting the `ISO_DATE_TIME` format. However, the time zone is optional is for ISO_DATE_TIME, so this may not be an issue.

Clearly, you're throwing spaghetti at the wall and hoping something would stick. Write a unit test and try to convert the string to whatever datetime object you want. Once you've done that, come back if you've a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring Config Class annotate the localdatetime field like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "unloadpathinfo")
public class YourConfiguration {

@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime offset;
```

In this example offset is the LocalDateTime Attribute we want Spring to inject from application.yml

If you look at the ISO_DATE_TIME you will find the correct pattern

In the Yaml put the config value like this:

```
unloadpathinfo:
offset: "2024-01-01T01:30:00.000+01:00"
```

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

You should just adapt the setter in the configuration class.

if your yaml is:

```
default-film-showings:
  filmShowings:
    - id: 1
      dateTime: 2018-07-13 21:00:00
```

then do this in your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="default-film-showings")
public class FilmShowings {
    private List<FilmShowing> filmShowings;

    //Constructors, Getters, setters etc.

    public static class FilmShowing {
        private Integer id;
        private Film film;
        private Theatre theatre;
        private LocalDateTime dateTime;

        //Constructors, Getters, setters etc.
        public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
          DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 
          HH:mm:ss");
          LocalDateTime formatDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
          this.dateTime= formatDateTime;
        }
    }
}
```