# Spring boot project with LocalDateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

Can you use LocalDateTime with a Spring Boot project and if so how?

I tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot) and added the dependancy and the line required in application.properties but I still get :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303137
```

When persisting data or trying to view existing data with dates created using Java.Util.Date.

Comment: You can use `java.time` types with any JPA provider that supports those types, and since those types are standard in JPA 2.2 then any compliant JPA 2.2 provider

Comment: Spring-boot is an opinionated framework. If you know how to get Springboot onto JPA2.2 please let me know.

Comment: Try removing from @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) from your entity fields.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got it to go. It required multiple changes to make both Hibernate & Springboot & Thymeleaf all work with Java 8 - LocalDateTime.

**Hibernate**

Add dependencies:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.0")
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8'
```

Add the following to application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

The annotations on my entities look like:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalDateTime somedate;
```

Although that didn't seem to be strictly needed.

**Thymeleaf**

add dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-java8time', version: '3.0.0.RELEASE'
```

Make sure it matches your Thymeleaf version.

In any HTML in the project your dates fields should now use #temporals instead of #dates. ie:

```
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(object.somedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}">12/12/2018</td>
```

**Spring boot**

In my Application.java class I added:

```
@Bean
public Java8TimeDialect java8TimeDialect() {
    return new Java8TimeDialect();
}
```

The following resources were invaluable:

http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/11/how-to-java-8-date-time-with-thymeleaf.html#comment-form (Thymeleaf/Springboot)

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/ (Hibernate)

Comment: For a date-only value without time-of-day, use `LocalDate` rather than `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: While I do not know your broader intentions, let me caution you about using `LocalDateTime` for date-time values. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So that class does *not* represent a moment on the timeline, only a range of potential moments. If you mean to represent a specific moment on the timeline, use the other java.time classes: `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: your answer mentions hibernate but lists jackson dependencies under that. Maybe you're missing something related to hibernate in your answer?