# How to use Java 8 LocalTime in RequestBody of a Spring Boot REST Endpoint

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, jackson

I am trying to use Java 8 LocalTime as an attribute in a request object. It seems  JSON parsing is not working properly and I get a HTTPStatus 400.
My model object:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Location {
private String name;
private LocalTime openTime;
....
    }
```

I am using Swagger to document and use the REST apis. This is how the model object looks in Swagger.

```
{
 "name": "string",
"openTime": {
  "hour": 8,
  "minute": 0,
  "nano": 0,
  "second": 0
 }
}
```

I am using JSR310 dependency for jackson

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring Boot version is  `1.5.9.RELEASE`

I have the following questions:

1. How do I make the parsing work?
2. I just need hour and minute. How can I configure it?
3. How do I get more detail about the nature of the exception here. My application logs are clean. I have an RestControllerAdvice configured for exception handling, which does not handle it

   ```
   @RestControllerAdvice
   public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
   @ExceptionHandler({ JsonMappingException.class })
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
     public List<ApplicationErrorDto> handle(JsonMappingException exception) {
     ApplicationErrorDto applicationErrorDto =  new ApplicationErrorDto();
     applicationErrorDto.setMessage("Request body is malformed");
     logger.info("Request body is malformed: " ,exception);
     return Arrays.asList(applicationErrorDto);
   }
   //methods for other exceptions
   }
   ```

   I tried following a similar link, but unable to solve it for myself so far: [JSON Java 8 LocalDateTime format in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot)

**EDIT-1------------------------------------------------------------**

I took @JBNizet's advice, returned Locatime from an controller(not an object containing LocalTime).
This is what I get:

```
[
  13,
  42,
  38,
  550000000
]
```

That's my local time. Then I used the following property in `application.properties`

> spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false

Using the property helped me to change the localtime to a more readable format: `"13:48:04.207"`

However, a POST endpoint that expects a LocalTime object, is interpreted by Swagger as:

```
{
 "hour": 0,
 "minute": 0,
 "nano": 0,
 "second": 0
}
```

Using this schema to POST a LocalTime throws the same 400 error. So, I just copied the structure I was getting in my GET URL and it started working.
Both of the following work:

1. `"13:48:04.207"`
2. `"13:48"`

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310: it's deprecated. You shouldn't use that module. The newer module has documentation, too: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime. Even without documentation, why don't you just experiment? Return an object containing a LocalTime from one of your controllers, and see how it's being serialized.

Comment: From my experience 400 (bad request) also occurs when something more general is a problem. Please provide you controller code and the client code accessing it (the generated stuff when you use swagger codegen).

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Swagger is not showing any response body, just the 400. I'm providing further updates in my original post.

Comment: So, what is your question now? The question you asked in your title is answered isn't it? You know what to send in the request body to your endpoint.

Comment: @JBNizet Question 1 and 2  are answered. Thanks.  Question 3, I still dont have an answer yet. I am also interested to know why Swagger interprets the RequestBody wrongly. May be I will do some digging around that.

Comment: answers should be contained in the answers section, and you should have one answerable question per topic. Voting to close until this is clarified.