# Can't convert Message object from RabbitMQ to java class

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I created my RabbitListener to get messages from RabbitMQ queue.

My rabbitMQ message:

```
Properties  
priority:   0
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
__TypeId__: com.kmb.bank.models.Transfer
content_encoding:   UTF-8
content_type:   application/json
Payload
356 bytes
Encoding: string


{"userAccountNumber":"1111444422221111","title":"123","recipientName":"123","recipientAccountNumber":"1234123412341234","amount":123.0,"localDateTime":{"nano":526106200,"year":2018,"monthValue":11,"dayOfMonth":29,"hour":20,"minute":43,"second":0,"month":"NOVEMBER","dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":333,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}
```

My Listener method:

```
@Autowired
private Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter;

@RabbitListener(queues = "kolejka")
public void listen(Message message) {
    try {
        Transfer transfer = (Transfer) jackson2JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage(message);
        log.info(transfer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error thrown while listening + " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Bean config:
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper());
}
```

And Transfer class:

```
package com.kmb.transactionlogger.models;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Transfer {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String userAccountNumber;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String title;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String recipientName;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String recipientAccountNumber;
    @Getter @Setter
    private double amount;
    @Getter @Setter
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

}
```

Unfortunately the exception is being thrown while converting from Message to Transfer transfer object.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.kmb.bank.models.Transfer]
2018-11-29 20:47:01.615  WARN 13688 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"userAccountNumber":"1111444422221111","title":"123","recipientName":"123","recipientAccountNumber":"1234123412341234","amount":123.0,"localDateTime":{"nano":599669800,"year":2018,"monthValue":11,"dayOfMonth":29,"hour":20,"minute":47,"second":1,"month":"NOVEMBER","dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":333,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}' MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.kmb.bank.models.Transfer}, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=bank, receivedRoutingKey=, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-sLNqW-_WhDWLWJk6MCQcjg, consumerQueue=kolejka])
```

Whole message log:
https://pastebin.com/raw/47Lq7dYD

Comment: Can you provide more detailed log (stacktrace)?

Comment: I think it's a problem that it's different Transfer class, package is different from __TypeId__, but I don't know the solution

Comment: You have to set up the type mapping in the receiving `jackson2JsonMessageConverter`'s type mapper to map to a different class. Alternatively, the framework will infer the type from the parameter if you use `public void listen(Transfer transfer)` if you wire the converter into the listener container factory. If it's a Boot app, that will happen automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set up the type mapping in the receiving `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`'s type mapper to map to a different class.

Generally the sender would map its class to a token, e.g. `transfer` and the receiver will map that to its version of `Transfer`.

Alternatively, the framework will infer the type from the parameter if you use `public void listen(Transfer transfer)`, and if you wire the converter into the listener container factory.

If it's a Spring Boot application, that wiring will happen automatically.

Comment: It helped a little, but now I am getting error connected with LocalDateTime:Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at

Comment: You need a custom Jackson deserializer applied to the ObjectMapper - here's one question that has answers about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and when i tried using custom message converters, some would throw errors while trying to resolve to the class specified on the header by the spring producer. I ended up converting the object class to a json string using `ObjectMapper` class.

One thing i would like to point is that, doing that will send the content to rabbit MQ as a stringified `JSON`. So you can receive it on the consumer class as a string, map it to another custom class using `objectMapper.read(stringType, mappedToClass)`.

Another advantage i have gotten is that i can directly read it in other consumers written in `python` or `nodejs`

In summary
In springboot when sending,
`rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, key, objectMapper.writeValueAsString())`.

In springboot consumer when reading to a custom object that does not have to
match the consumer object.
`CustomObj obj = objectMapper.read(incomingString, CustomObj.class)`.

> A point to note is that, make sure to `ignoreUnknown` fields in the custom object class,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set message converter for both **producer and consumer**. So when producer sends your object, it will auto convert the object to Json and when consumer receives your Json message, it will auto convert the Json message to original object.

```html
   // 1. producer converter config

   @Bean("Jackson2JsonMessageConverter")
      Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter() {
         return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

// 2. consumer converter config

@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.queueName, messageConverter = "Jackson2JsonMessageConverter")
public void receiveMessage(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Object) {
        LOG.info("receiveMessage" + message.toString());
    }
}


// 3. send message which is an Java Object

rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("topicExchangeName", "routing.key.test", Object);
```

POM:

```html
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Full example:**
[gs-messaging-rabbitmq](https://github.com/letrthang/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/tree/main/advance)