# Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.util.Date

Tags: spring, datetime, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, datetime-format

`[Spring + Kotlin]`

These are the dependencies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
```

This is the Entity:

```
@Entity
class MatchEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long,
        @NotBlank val matchDateTime: Date,
        @NotBlank @ManyToOne @JoinColumn val tournamentInvolved: TournamentEntity
)
```

Whenever I try to run the following query:

```
interface MatchRepository : JpaRepository<MatchEntity, Long> {
    fun findMatchesByMatchDateTimeIsAfter(matchDateTime: Date)
}
```

with a test string like so `1985-04-12T23:20`, I get the error:

```
QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.util.Date!
```

I tried, as suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters), with patterns like `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)` and  `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` in the signature of the query method, without solving.

Also, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot), I tried adding

1. `compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.0")` to the dependencies
2. `spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false` to the application.properties.

Didn't work.

**UPDATE:**
I also tried with LocalDateTime and Instant classes. Still getting the same Exceptions:

`QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.time.LocalDateTime!`

`QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.time.Instant!`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`; both classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I just tried, i got these messages:

`QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.time.LocalDateTime!`


`QueryMethodParameterConversionException: Failed to convert 1985-04-12T23:20 into java.time.Instant!`

Comment: Try adding seconds to the date you are submitting. (ISO-8601 the default includes seconds).

Comment: Turned out the problem was the @DateTimeFormat pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

Using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")` worked.