# How to format a LocalDateTime field in a POJO persisted to a BLOB

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot, localdatetime

I have a POJO that I'm storing in `JSON` format in a `BLOB` column on a MySQL database table.  The POJO in question has a `LocalDateTime` field and whenever I persist data to the column the `LocalDateTime` field takes the format described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot), whereas I would like it to be represented in the format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

I have tried implementing the solutions suggested in the linked post but none of them have worked.  My guess is that it's something to do with the fact that the field is part of a POJO in a `BLOB` as opposed to a traditional `Timestamp` field.

This is the code of my POJO as it stands

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private String someText;

    //Constructors

    //Getters and setters

}
```

Any input would be welcome.

This is the current JSON output:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"dateTime" : {
    "year" : 2010,
    "month" : "JANUARY",
    "dayOfMonth" : 1,
    "dayOfWeek" : "FRIDAY",
    "dayOfYear" : 1,
    "monthValue" : 1,
    "hour" : 2,
    "minute" : 2,
    "second" : 0,
    "nano" : 0,
    "chronology" : {
      "id" : "ISO",
      "calendarType" : "iso8601"
    }
  }, 
  "someText": "someText"
}
```

Comment: Just use `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")` on field nothing else, it should work. make sure you are sending exact MyPOJO object as response

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` because you also need those time value. if no replace with LocalDate and leave your current format of regex.

Answer (score 0):

The correct annotation for your case should be:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

The full question describing this solution could be found here: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization). But also, why do you persist your POJO into BLOB? at the very least, use CLOB (BLOB stands for **B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject, and CLOB stands for **C**haracter **L**arge **OB**ject). But really you probably should concider VARCHAR2 field that should be enough in most if not all the cases.