# Jackson failing to de-serialize LocalDateTime with valid format

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have the following field annotated with `JsonFormat`, but de-serialization is failing,

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@NotBlank
private LocalDateTime transactionTime;
```

Failure message,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2024-01-31 14:25:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2024-01-31 14:25:00' could not be parsed at index 10
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
```

However, if I use `JsonDeserialize` and `JsonSerialize`, it works fine, although the format isn't what I want.
Any ideas on how to solve this ?

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@NotBlank
private LocalDateTime transactionTime;
```

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the code of LocalDateTimeDeserializer. Anyway, the "index 10" where the parser fails is the space separating the date and the time. So there must be something wrong with the way you created the DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot/29959842#29959842