# Serialization of Java 8 ZonedDateTime with Jackson and JavaTimeModule

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, java-8

I'm trying to use Jackson to serialize and deserialize objects (marshall/unmarshall) from and to JSON. Some of these objects have Java 8 LocalDate and ZonedDateTime. I've read here that the best option is to use [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)

[serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper)

However, when I try to use this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V from class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
```

Any clue? I'm using Jackson 2.6.0, jackson-datatype-jsr310 2.6.0 and am deploying to Tomcat 8.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end, the problem was I had a different version of Jackson, due to a dependency with Jongo. jackson-datatype-jsr310 2.6.0 needs Jackson 2.6.0 and Jackson 2.4.1 was being deployed.

Comment: I had the same problem with `java.time.LocalDate` and resolved it using the same version of `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind`. In my case it was version 2.7.4 for both dependencies.