# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:Cannot construct instance of`java.time.Instant`(no Creators,like default construct):

Tags: json, jackson

I already went through link: [JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.time.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863678/json-parse-error-can-not-construct-instance-of-java-time-localdate-no-string-a/50932575), but getting below error.

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-08-28T15:15:44.183Z')
```

Java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StudentResponse {
    private Integer a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to parse a JSON where `Instant` field is `"2019-08-28T15:15:44.183Z"`

First of all, ensure you have a dependency. E.g. in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use this dependency and not (de)serialize `Instant` as timestamps that it does by default. I setup my `ObjectMapper` as:

```
ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper()
        .findAndRegisterModules()
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```