# Kotlin data class and LocalDateTime

Tags: kotlin, jackson, localdate, data-class

I have Ticket class:

```
data class Ticket(
        var contact_email : String? = null,
        var date_opened : LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

but I get error during read from string:

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like
>   default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('2017-11-13T06:40:00Z')  at
>   [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
>   rnd_classifier.model.Ticket["date_opened"])

I tried add annotations without success:

```
data class Ticket(
        var contact_email : String? = null,

        @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)
        @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer::class)
        var date_opened : LocalDateTime? = null
)
```

How to fixed it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is more about jackson rather than kotlin.
As stated in [serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper)

you need to add an additional gradle dependency to solve it

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.5")
```

after that it should work

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import java.time.LocalDateTime

class SoTest {

    data class Ticket(
            var contact_email: String? = null,
            var date_opened: LocalDateTime? = null
    )

    @Test
    fun checkSerialize() {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        val ticket = mapper.readValue(inputJsonString, Ticket::class.java)
        assert ("$ticket"=="Ticket(contact_email=contact@ema.il, date_opened=2017-11-13T06:40)")
    }

    val inputJsonString = """{
        "contact_email": "contact@ema.il",
        "date_opened": "2017-11-13T06:40:00Z"
    }""".trimIndent()

}
```