# How to show Java8 LocalTime as a string in Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have **swagger 2.8.0** and My POJO class is as follows,

```
public class Item {

   @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
   private LocalDate date;

   @JsonFormat(pattern="HH:mm")
   private LocalTime time;

   // other fields and Getters and Setters are omitted for brevity
}
```

Now in the swagger-ui, in the example value section, my POJO model is shown as

```
{
  "date": "string",
  "time": {
    "hour": 0,
    "minute": 0,
    "nano": 0,
    "second": 0
  }
}
```

How to show the LocalTime as a string in the swagger-ui?

Comment: Related to and possible duplicate of [serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper)

Comment: The above one is related to marshalling and unmarshalling of java8 dates. But this question is regarding the swagger-ui, how to change the example value and model representation in swagger-ui. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in the swagger config

**directModelSubstitute** will resolve this issue

```
@Bean
   public Docket postsApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)//.groupName("public-api")
              .groupName("")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, String.class)
               .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
               .directModelSubstitute(LocalTime.class, String.class)
               .directModelSubstitute(ZonedDateTime.class, String.class)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))

            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .paths(postPaths()).build().useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, getCustomizedResponseMessages());
   }
```

Comment: This is the exact answer. Thanks

Comment: Do you know a solution for springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui? There is no Docket class

Answer (score 1):

For springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui you can add Schema annotation

```
@Schema(type = "String", pattern = "HH:mm:SS")
LocalTime localTime
```

Comment: works for generated openapi.yaml/JSON-specification (but enforces give-up of the generated ApiClient types, by means String as well instead of LocalTime)

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented static **public** method called [PrimitiveType.enablePartialTime()](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/74d826dee89e8af0a87e664cd4e5485141877047/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/core/util/PrimitiveType.java#L438). When you run this method during the loading context phase, it adds `java.util.LocalTime` to the list of primitive types and translates it into the `string` type with a `partial-time` format.

I needed to use it in an XML definition so I used the following configuration:

```
<bean name="localTimeFixer" class="io.swagger.v3.core.util.PrimitiveType" factory-method="enablePartialTime"/>
```

However, in *annotated* or *Spring Boot* contexts, it's even simpler, as you can call this method directly within an initialization bean.

```
PrimitiveType.enablePartialTime()
```

It's in the library since version `2.0.6` where the [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2992) was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

found such solution [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1276842/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-localtime-%D0%B2-springdoc).

[time format in Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEPEl.png)

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springdoc.core.utils.SpringDocUtils;

static {
        var schema = new Schema<LocalTime>();
        schema.example(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")));
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalTime.class, schema);
    }
```