# Spring Boot Test: UserControllerTest Fails When Using Jackson ObjectMapper To Convert Model To JSON String

Tags: java, validation, objectmapper, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm testing a `@RestContoller` in Spring Boot which has a `@PostMapping` method and the method `@RequestBody` is validated using `@Valid` annotation. To test it, I'm using `MockMvc` and in order to populate request body content I'm using `Jackson ObjectMapper`; however, when the model is passed, the test fails:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/user/register
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.springboottutorial.todoapp.controller.UserController
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.springboottutorial.todoapp.controller.UserController.register(com.springboottutorial.todoapp.dao.model.User)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :400
```

User Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"EMAIL"}))
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
@NotNull
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
@NotNull
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
@NotNull
@Email
private String emailAddress;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
@NotNull
private String password;

@Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
@NotNull
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConveter.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

@Column(name = "UPDATED_AT")
@NotNull
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConveter.class)
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

public User(@NotNull String firstName, @NotNull String lastName,
                @NotNull @Email String emailAddress, @NotNull String password,
                @NotNull LocalDateTime createdAt, @NotNull LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

//setters and getters: omitted
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody @Valid User user){
        userService.createUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

UserControllerTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void whenRequestValid_thenReturnStatusOk() throws Exception{
        User user = new User("John", "QPublic", "john.public@gmail.com",
                "123456789", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());      
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/user/register")
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

When I build JSON string manually, the test passes:

```
String json = "{\n" +
                "\t\"firstName\" : \"John\",\n" +
                "\t\"lastName\" : \"QPublic\",\n" +
                "\t\"password\" : \"123456789\",\n" +
                "\t\"createdAt\" : \"2016-11-09T11:44:44.797\",\n" +
                "\t\"updatedAt\" : \"2016-11-09T11:44:44.797\",\n" +
                "\t\"emailAddress\" : \"john.public@gmail.com\"\n" +
                "}";

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/user/register")
                .content(json)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

Comment: Did you run the application for checking if the endpoint is working with Postman or another similar tool ?. Please include your `pom.xml` in your answer

Comment: Did you try printing out the string returned by `writeValueAsString` to validate it? (I _very_ strongly suspect you're getting a "timestamp" format, and don't use `Local*` for anything except user calendars; use `Instant` instead.)

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek Yes, it runs properly when I use postman tool.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for your suggestion! LocalDateTime parsed to days, month, years when mapped to JSON string so the conflict came up. I made LocalDateTime nullable and this time it worked out. I'm trying to come up with a solid solution and post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chrylis mentioned in comments, the problem occurred due to Java 8 Date & Time API and Jackson serialization conflicts. By default, `ObjectMapper` doesn't understand the `LocalDateTime` data type, so I need to add `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency to my maven which is a datatype module to make Jackson recognize Java 8 Date & Time API data types. A [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper) and a [blog post](https://touk.pl/blog/2016/02/12/formatting-java-time-with-spring-boot-using-json/) helped me to figure out what actually my problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Spring is not necessarily providing you with a "vanilla" ObjectMapper instance. By having Spring inject the `ObjectMapper` instance into the test instead of creating an `ObjectMapper` with the default constructor, you will get an instance that matches your actual run-time environment, provided that your Spring profile for your unit tests is set up correctly.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void whenRequestValid_thenReturnStatusOk() throws Exception{
        User user = new User("John", "QPublic", "john.public@gmail.com",
                "123456789", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());      
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/user/register")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implement my rest controllers test. Maybe It could help you.

I've this abstract class to encapsulate common tests functionalities regarding to the *JSON* mapping.

```java
    import lombok.SneakyThrows;
    import lombok.val;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.mock.http.MockHttpOutputMessage;

    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

    public abstract class RestControllerTest {

        private final MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        private HttpMessageConverter messageConverter;

        protected MediaType getContentType() {
            return contentType;
        }

        @Autowired
        void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {
            messageConverter = Arrays.stream(converters)
                    .filter(hmc -> hmc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);

            assertNotNull("the JSON message converter must not be null",
                    messageConverter);
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        protected String toJson(Object data) {
            val mockHttpOutputMessage = new MockHttpOutputMessage();
            messageConverter.write(
                    data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, mockHttpOutputMessage);
            return mockHttpOutputMessage.getBodyAsString();
        }
    }
```

You could use it in your test class like this

```java
    @WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
    public class UserControllerTest extends RestControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Test
        public void whenRequestValid_thenReturnStatusOk() throws Exception{
            User user = new User("John", "QPublic", "john.public@gmail.com",
                    "123456789", LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());      
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/user/register")
                    .content(toJson(user))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    )
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        }
    }
```

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

If `LocalDateTime` is not a problem, I think we should implement`equals` in User class.