# Spring RequestBody cannot parse datetime timezone correctly

Tags: java, spring, datetime

I have a simple rest service to store time range, however, Spring cannot parse datetime format with timezone correctly.

the Entity is

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TimeRange {
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = true)
private LocalDateTime startTime;

@Column(nullable = true)
private LocalDateTime endTime;
}
```

The controller is:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/time", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Boolean setTime(@RequestBody TimeRange timeRange) {
    timeRangeRepository.save(timeRange);
    return true;
}
```

and the actuall request is

```
url = f'http://localhost/api/time'
data = {
  "startTime": "2019-12-03T19:58:29.047820+08:00",
  "endTime": "2019-12-04T19:58:29.047820+08:00"}
resp = requests.post(url, json=data, timeout=10)
pprint(resp.json())
```

spring reported an error said:

```
 esolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: 
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2019-12-
```

03T19:58:29.047820+08:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: 
    (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-12-03T19:58:29.047820+08:00' could not be 
    parsed, unparsed text found at index 26; nested exception is 
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type 
    `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2019-12-03T19:58:29.047820+08:00": Failed to deserialize 
   java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-12- 
  03T19:58:29.047820+08:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 26
    at

Comment: Does this answer your question? [serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper)

Comment: tried the jackson-modules-java8, it still get the same error, i might not be able to get 
 findAndRegisterModules  on the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Comment: This is a duplicated question. Look at the question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Comment: Do you intentionally want to deserialize to `java.time.LocalDateTime` (losing the zone informat) instead of `java.time.ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: @MichaelGantman That is not a duplicate of this question. Given that the OPs code is already deserializing to `java.time` classes, that is already setup, the problem is that they're trying to deserialize a timestamp with zone information to a `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a date with offset, if all your date comes in the same format you can create a custom deserializer like this

```
public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer () {
        this(null);
    }

    protected CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer (Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(arg0.getValueAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }

}
```

and the annotate your fields with `@JsonDeserialize`

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime startTime;

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime endTime;
```

And if you want to serialize your dates with the same format, you have to create a custom serializer

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your LocalDateTime fields with:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
```