# How to change Duration Format in JSON Java

Tags: java

I have a class with some field

```
public class SomeClass {
   private Duration discussionTime;
}
```

When i try to send this class to frontend using `@RestController` in Spring, i see that answer:

```
"discussionTime": {
                "seconds": 7,
                "zero": false,
                "negative": false,
                "nano": 72000000,
                "units": [
                    "SECONDS",
                    "NANOS"
                ]
            }
```

Is there ways to set format of answer to
`"discussionTime": 7` ?

Comment: Either through custom mapping to a new object, or by creating your own serializer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952473/2082699

But if you only want the seconds, might be best to just create a new object you serialize instead of messing with the Duration.

Comment: @TomCools Yes, it really work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you upvote my answer in this case, so others can see this as well?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this:

- custom mapping to a new object (instead of returning a Duration)
- by creating your own serializer: [serialize/deserialize java 8 java.time with Jackson JSON mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper/27952473#27952473)

**But if you only want the seconds, might be best to just create a new object you serialize instead of messing with the Duration.**

Answer (score 2):

An option could be to use a [MixIn](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Also [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) could help you.

Depending on your use case you can create your own serializer as suggested by others or go for a more generic solution if you have to do this in multiple places.

Or maybe:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private Duration discussionTime;

  @JsonProperty("discussionTime")
  public long getDiscussionTimeSeconds() {
      return discussionTime.getSeconds();
  }
}
```