# Why can't I deserialize a Joda DateTime?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jodatime

I am getting error when we try to map ResultSet of stored procedure.

> could not deserialize

Result setmapping class:

```
 @NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery( name = "callCurriculumSearchProc", query = "EXEC curriculumSearchProcedure :academy_id,:curriculum_id,:curriulum_abbr,:demand_forecasting," + ":event_custodian_id,:pre_post_flag,:reviewed_date,:is_active,:id", resultSetMapping = "curriculumSearchResult" ) }) @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "curriculumSearchResult", classes = { @ConstructorResult(targetClass = CurriculumSearchResult.class, columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "id" ,type = Long.class), @ColumnResult(name = "curriculum_name"), @ColumnResult(name = "cirriculum_abbr"), @ColumnResult(name = "academy_name"), @ColumnResult(name = "academy_short_Name"), @ColumnResult(name = "reviewed_date", type = DateTime.class), @ColumnResult(name = "custodian")}) })

@MappedSuperclass public class CurriculumSearchResult implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "curriculum_name")
private String curriculum_name;

@Column(name = "curriculum_abbr")
private String curriculum_abbr;

@Column(name = "academy_name")
private String academy_name;

@Column(name = "academy_short_Name")
private String academy_short_name;

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@Column(name = "reviewed_date")
private DateTime reviewed_date;

@Column(name = "custodian")
private String eventCustodian;

public CurriculumSearchResult (){

}
public CurriculumSearchResult(Long id, String curriculum_name, String curriculum_abbr, String academy_name, String academy_short_name, DateTime reviewed_date, String eventCustodian) { super(); this.id = id; this.curriculum_name = curriculum_name; this.curriculum_abbr = curriculum_abbr; this.academy_name = academy_name; this.academy_short_name = academy_short_name; this.reviewed_date = reviewed_date; this.eventCustodian = eventCustodian; }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCurriculum_name() {
    return curriculum_name;
}

public void setCurriculum_name(String curriculum_name) {
    this.curriculum_name = curriculum_name;
}

public String getCurriculum_abbr() {
    return curriculum_abbr;
}

public void setCurriculum_abbr(String curriculum_abbr) {
    this.curriculum_abbr = curriculum_abbr;
}

public String getAcademy_name() {
    return academy_name;
}

public void setAcademy_name(String academy_name) {
    this.academy_name = academy_name;
}

public String getAcademy_short_name() {
    return academy_short_name;
}

public void setAcademy_short_name(String academy_short_name) {
    this.academy_short_name = academy_short_name;
}

public DateTime getReviewed_date() {
    return reviewed_date;
}

public void setReviewed_date(DateTime reviewed_date) {
    this.reviewed_date = reviewed_date;
}

public String getEventCustodian() {
    return eventCustodian;
}

public void setEventCustodian(String eventCustodian) {
    this.eventCustodian = eventCustodian;
}

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CurriculumSearchResult [id=" + id + ", curriculum_name="
            + curriculum_name + ", curriculum_abbr=" + curriculum_abbr
            + ", academy_name=" + academy_name + ", academy_short_name="
            + academy_short_name + ", reviewed_date=" + reviewed_date
            + ", eventCustodian=" + eventCustodian + "]";
}
}
```

I get this error when there is value in `reviewed_date` column, but it works well when value is null.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual error you're getting. Also, for future reference, if you want people to see your quesiton, tag it with the language it's using and all the relevant technologies. This is obviously a Jackson problem, not a spring problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize Joda DateTime with Jackson JSON processer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269459/how-to-serialize-joda-datetime-with-jackson-json-processer)