# Joda time serialization (Spring Boot 1.3.1)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime

I cannot serialize a date of type `org.joda.time.DateTime` with `spring boot 1.3.1.`
I have included the following dependencies:

```
joda-time:joda-time
```

`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda`

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but it is not related to Spring Boot. It's got to do with the Jackson not recognizing the "DateTime" data type. I converted the datetime to a String before serialization.

However it is possible to directly serializing it by registering the Jackson module while initializing the ObjectMapper object. Check out [How to serialize Joda DateTime with Jackson JSON processer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269459/how-to-serialize-joda-datetime-with-jackson-json-processer)