# Jackson JavaTimeModule for Joda Time?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime

I would like to set global Jackson serialization setting for Local Date and use something like [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.java) for `java.time` but for JodaTime's Local Date.

Does something like `JavaTimeModule` exist for Joda Time?

Comment: see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda

Comment: possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269459/how-to-serialize-joda-datetime-with-jackson-json-processer?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes exists. Take a look at: [JodaModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda)