# Swagger Codegen Java client Date format

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have a java client in swagger whose swagger.json includes the following:

```
"updatedTime":{"type":"string","format":"date-time"}
```

[This](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1035) issue from 2015 says specifying the format as `date-time` doesn't use `Joda DateTime`. For my client I want to have the property represented as `java.util.Date` rather than the `Joda` representation. I tried using `-DdateLibrary=java8`, but that prevents the client from using the feign builder when I generate my client using the following command:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://localhost:8080/swagger.json -l java --library feign -DdateLibrary=java8 -o samples/client/my-service/java
```

How can I specify what data type swagger should use for the response object? In fact on the service, the property is already represented as `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of dealing with swagger, we can deal with Jackson serialization
add the dependency on `pom.xml`:

```xml
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
jackson-datatype-jsr310
2.4.0
```

and add `JodaModule` on your `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Just go through the link: [How to serialize Joda DateTime with Jackson JSON processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269459/how-to-serialize-joda-datetime-with-jackson-json-processer)